# GORM thread-safe connection

Tags: go, go-gorm, cockroachdb

I have simple code on golang which is executed while receive request and update a value on database.

```
res := db.Where(ExampleStructforDB{Id: Id}).FirstOrCreate(&ls)
    if res.Error != nil {
        log.Error(res.Error)
        return res.Error
    }
ls.count += 1

err = Db.Save(&ls).Error
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
    return err
}
```

Sometimes I see that there is a race condition.Time-to-time some of the requests gets same value from database for updating.But in fact that, every request is increase or decrease count on db.

As far as I understand, GORM says that it should be use `Session`.
https://gorm.io/docs/session.html

Is it right approach for it ?

Comment: Run the `Where` and `Save` operations within a `db.Transaction`.

Comment: Thanks so much.I will replace the code like below and will check it the effect.
with manually control transaction.

```
db := Db.Session(&gorm.Session{}).Begin()
res := db.Where(ExampleStructforDB{Id: Id}).FirstOrCreate(&ls)
```
@BurakSerdar